# How to checked checkbox/radiobox values from database with ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, codeigniter-3

Good day! I have a problem when  updating value from database via ajax request. It doesn't checked the checkbox as well the radio box.The select option works fine. Did I missed something?
 Here is my current Ajax code :

```
    function editUser(user_id) {
    $('#addUser').css("display", "none");
    $('#updateUser').css("display", "");

    $.post(baseurl + 'globalFunction/getUserData', {

        user_id: user_id

    }, function (data) {
        var result = eval('(' + data + ')');

        $('#username').val(result[0].user_username);
        $('#group_select option[value="' + result[0].user_group_id + '"]').prop("selected", true);
        $('#sub_group_select option[value="' + result[0].sub_group_id + '"]').prop("selected", true);
        $("[name=userType_edit]").filter("[value="+ result[0].user_type+"]").attr("checked","checked");
    $('.check_perm input[value="'+ result[0].perm_id +'"]').prop('checked', true);

    })

}
```

My Php:

```
 function getUserData(){

        $user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');

        $sql = $this->crud->getData("tbl_user as u,tbl_group as g, tbl_sub_group as sg, tbl_user_permission as up", "u.user_id='$user_id' AND u.user_group_id=g.group_id AND u.user_sub_group_id = sg.sub_group_id AND up.user_id ='$user_id'")['rows'];

        echo json_encode($sql);
}
```

my HTML radiobox:

```
<div class="radio-list">
                                            <label class="radio">
                                                <input type="radio" class="userType_radio" name="userType_edit"  value="President"> President </label>
                                            <label class="radio">
                                                <input type="radio"class="userType_radio" name="userType_edit"  value="Vice President"> Vice President </label>
                                            <label class="radio">
                                                <input type="radio"class="userType_radio" name="userType_edit" value="Dean"> Dean </label>
                                            <label class="radio">
                                                <input type="radio"class="userType_radio" name="userType_edit"  value="Staff"> Staff </label>
                                            <label class="radio">
                                                <input type="radio"class="userType_radio" name="userType_edit"  value="Area Head"> Area Head </label>
                                            <label class="radio">
                                                <input type="radio"class="userType_radio" name="userType_edit"  value="Adviser"> Adviser </label>
                                            <label class="radio">
                                                <input type="radio"class="userType_radio" name="userType_edit"  value="Faculty"> Faculty </label>
                                            <label class="radio">
                                                <input type="radio"class="userType_radio" name="userType_edit"  value="Student"> Student </label>
                                        </div>
```

php checkbox:

```
function selectOptionUserPermissionList(){

$sql=$this->crud->getData("tbl_permission","perm_status = '1'");

$data='';
    foreach($sql['rows'] as $key){
    $data.='<label><input type="checkbox" class="icheck check_permission check_perm" name="permission[]" id="'.$key->perm_id.'" value="'.$key->perm_id.'">' . $key->perm_description.'</label>';
}

$result['a']= $data;

echo json_encode($result);
```

}

I'm using codeigniter.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: man why people run from posting the html

Comment: what do u mean?

Comment: skip that, what is the purpose of the ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check whether this can help. To check the radio button please use

```
$("input:radio[name=userType_edit][value="+result[0].user_type+"]").prop( 'checked', true );
```

Regarding check box not sure what you are missing.

I hope below is the line you are trying to check check boxes.

```
$('.check_perm input[value="'+ result[0].perm_id +'"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Above line is valid but I suggest check the selector you are using.

You can use

```
console.log( $('.check_perm input[value="'+ result[0].perm_id +'"]').length)
```

to check how many elements the jQuery is returning.

Comment: the radio button doesn't checked the box but in the console the value was showed. And in the checkbox it returns 0. But why? where did I go wrong?

Comment: @ShakeyShake If the radio button in the group has not checked please check the value in result[0].user_type. if the value in result[0].user_type is not assigned to any input type radio button with value attribute then you need to check the values you are assigning to the radio buttons. Secondly also check the value returned from you ajax call and make sure that value has assigned to one of the check box. good luck.

Comment: Still not working. I had checked everything and all the datas are correct except that radio button is not working.. Please help me with this. This is my thesis/capstone project :(

Comment: I had found a solution of my problem. My html template uses jquery.uniform.js  and it wraps the input radio with span. That's why the radio button was not checked. 

I add this code:

'$.uniform.update('input[type=radio][name=userType_edit]');'

 Anyways, thank you for the help :)